# CONTAINS does not / no longer finds values in large strings

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

In CosmosDB we store some documents with large string fields. These are audit records. From time to time we search these fields with the following sql:

```
select * from c where contains(c.Body, "123456789")
```

We have been doing this for at least a year. Sometime in the past couple of months the above query will no longer return values where it used to. As in I can repeat this query for values that used to work but it no longer works.

If I copy the document to the local emulator the query works there.

Has a limit been implemented?

Comment: The only change to the [CONTAINS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-contains) function is we added an optional switch to do case insensitive search but the function works as before without it. Does it return some values or none at all? Are you sure you're draining the result set? Have you tried running in the portal and looking at the query stats to see if it's using the index?

Answer (score 0):

Checked on this and there was a recent change with CONTAINS to utilize the index. If you file a support ticket we can take a closer look and can revert the behavior if needed. You can also revert to the old behavior by excluding the path to this property from the index.

Thanks.

Comment: Mark, thank you. Azure support let me know what was going on and reverted our accounts to the old behaviour.